# Powershell Error for Get-Service

Tags: powershell

Back when I had Windows 7 an a lower version of Powershell the following code use to work without any issues.

It checks each server in a text file for some services and dumps the results to a CSV.

Now that I'm on Windows 10 and with Powershell v5 I get this error message:

> ```
> Get-Service : Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer 'tfsserver1'. This operation might require other privileges. At
> C:\Users\Razon\Desktop\Patching\ServerServices_Checker_v2.ps1:48
> char:4
> +         (Get-Service -Name TFSJobAgent*,IIS*,World* -ComputerName $_) | Select Machine ...
> +          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>      + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Service], InvalidOperationException
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand
> ```

```
 ####System Varialbe to User's Deskotp
 $filePath = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")
```

Here is the code:

```
function tfsCheck 
{
    $Path = "$filePath\Patching\Servers\tfs_servers.txt"
    Get-Content $Path | foreach {
        (Get-Service -Name TFSJobAgent*,IIS*,World* -ComputerName $_) | Select MachineName, Status, DisplayName
    }
}

#TFS Function Call and Write to CSV
tfsCheck|Select MachineName, Status, DisplayName |Export-Csv $filePath\Patching\Results\TFS_ServicesResults.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Is PSRemoting enabled on your remote server? Have you added it to your TrustedHosts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue, elevate the user's network privileges to be able to access the Service Control Manager on the Server.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/964206/cannot-open-service-control-manager-on-computer-servername-.-this-operation-might-require-other-privileges

Comment: It's not this. It works some times without any errors in ISE Run as Admin or PowerShell as Admin.

Comment: Does anyone know HOW this is done? The article doesn't have much information.

Comment: Link to example is dead.